# Custom control is not active

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I have created custom control.

I want to use it but the control is not active.
[image]

Any idea how can I make the customs control active?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Not Active" means what?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the solution?

Comment: It could be that those components aren't designed for WinForms.  You *might* have to reset the toolbox.  Right click it, choose "Reset Toolbox"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once and all my custom controls in toolbox were grayed out. I could seem them but they were disabled in Visual Studio 2010. I fixed it by right clicking on the toolbox item then reset toolbox.